# How do you make combined rolling groups in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do you get rolling groups in Pandas I need the following group (1,2), then group (2,3), then group (3,4), etc. The best i can do is group (1,2), then group (3,4).  I take group 1, add the values to group 2. Then the next iteration is group (2,3). I take group 2's newly updated values, and add them to group 3's original values.  I then take those group 3 newly updated values, and add them to group 4's original values, so we get:

The most important parts of this, don't get stuck on adding the values in the right order, really the most important thing is that i want to update a group, i want to update group 2, with group 1's values (my post is just an example) , then in the next transform, i want those new group values i updated in group2 to update the next group, which is 3. Then in the next transform or apply, I want those new group 3 values so i can update group4. I hope that makes sense

```
num group
1       1
2       1
2       1
4       1
5       2
6       2
7       2
8       2
9       3
10      3
11      3
12      3
13      4
14      4
15      4
16      4
```

```
df=pd.read_clipboard()
```

I want my first group to be the following. group two has had it's values added by group 1:

```
1       1
2       1
3       1
4       1
6       2
8       2
10      2
14      2
```

My second group will then hopefully be the new modified values due to adding group one to them. group 3 will have it's original values added by group 2's new values:

```
6       2
8       2
10      2
14      2
15      3
18      3
21      3
26      3
```

My third group to be group 3's new values. and group four will be it's original values added by group 3 in order:

```
15      3
18      3
21      3
26      3
29      4
33      4
36      4
42      4
```

I tried

```
df.groupby(np.arrange(len(df))//4))
```

, except it only splits it by groups (1,2) the then the next group is (3,4). I need (1,2), (2,3), (3,4). This is due to me processing group 1 to make group 2's values. I then use group 2 to create group 3's values. I then use group 3 to make group 4's values.  Any help on this would be appreciated. I made a simple example because I don't need help with what I'm doing with the groups, I just need to know how to group like that.

Again, this is just an example, The most important parts of this, don't get stuck on adding the values in the right order, i'm not trying to test anyone.  really the most important thing is that i want to update a group, i want to update group 2, with group 1's values (my post is just an example) , then in the next transform, i want those new group values i updated in group2 to update the next group, which is 3. Then in the next transform or apply, I want those new group 3 values so i can update group4. I hope that makes sense

Comment: Actually i'm updating it, it's a quick update. my question to update it a bit more, thanks for those who answered, a better/clearer version will be online soon

Comment: just edit this one it's fine

Comment: My apologies, i wanted to make the question more clear. I hope that when you groupby like this and modify the values it is retained in the rolling group. Any best practices for how to do this will be greatly appreciated.  I am using group one to update group 2. Then with group 2's new values, i'm updating group 3's values. Then with group 3's new values, i'm updating group 4's new values. I'm hoping there is a way to groupby and transform so i can avoid for loops or splitting this without too much code

Comment: Like a rolling cumulative sum that only changes every four indices?

Comment: Like i use group 1 to make group 2's values. I solve in group 1 with a formula, and those answers go to group 2.  So then i need to take those new answers in group 2, apply the same formula and place the answers in group 3. Then i take my new group 3, apply a formula, and place those answers in group 4. That's the most important part to me then getting the answer right. I want to do something like df.groupby((1,2), (2,3), (3,4).transform( lambda x: take group 1 and do something and put them in group2. Then take those new group 2 answers do the same thing, and place them in group3, etc)

Answer (score 3):

I will do

```
s=df.group.drop_duplicates()
l=[df.loc[df.group.isin([x,y])]for x , y in zip(s.iloc[1:],s.shift().iloc[1:])]
```

Update

```
df['num']=df['num'].groupby(df.groupby('group').cumcount()).cumsum()
s=df.group.drop_duplicates()
l=[df.loc[df.group.isin([x,y])]for x , y in zip(s.iloc[1:],s.shift().iloc[1:])]
l[0]
   num  group
0    1      1
1    2      1
2    2      1
3    4      1
4    6      2
5    8      2
6    9      2
7   12      2
```

Comment: happy new year mate =)

Comment: @Datanovice happy new year :-)

Comment: I updated my answer a bit on what i'm really trying to accomplish, can you take a look again, i appreciate your current answer

Comment: @oppressionslayer check the update mate :-) and happy new year

Answer (score 2):

```
df['grp'] = df.apply(lambda x : x.iloc[::4]).groupby('num').cumsum()
df['grp'] = df['grp'].ffill()
print(df)
    num  group  grp
0     1      1  1.0
1     2      1  1.0
2     3      1  1.0
3     4      1  1.0
4     5      2  2.0
5     6      2  2.0
6     7      2  2.0
7     8      2  2.0
8     9      3  3.0
9    10      3  3.0
10   11      3  3.0
11   12      3  3.0
12   13      4  4.0
13   14      4  4.0
14   15      4  4.0
15   16      4  4.0
```

Comment: I updated my answer a bit on what i'm really trying to accomplish, can you take a look again, i appreciate your current answer

Answer (score 2):

Prerequisites:

```py
df["group_sub"]=df.groupby("group").cumcount()
dfprev=df["num"]
for i in range(1, df.group.nunique()):
    dfprev+=df["num"].groupby(df["group_sub"]).shift(i).fillna(0) 
df.drop("group_sub", axis=1, inplace=True)
```

You can do:

```py
df_series=[df.loc[df.group.isin(df.group.unique()[i:i+2])] for i in range(df.group.nunique()-1)]
```

Comment: I updated my answer a bit on what i'm really trying to accomplish, can you take a look again, i appreciate your current answer

Comment: I added prerequisites - let me know, if that's right direction. Will explore some more in the morning, happy new year ;)